# Limiting a SPARQL Query to Lastest Point in Time

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia, sparql

I'm trying to get information on Prefectures in Japan out of Wikidata. I succeeded to read the `population` statement, however there are occasionally several values with different `point in time` fields.

```
SELECT ?itemLabel ?population ?date 
WHERE {
   ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q50337;
         p:P1082 [pq:P585 ?date; ps:P1082 ?population];

   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

I'm was trying to get a single row per prefecture using groups, but to no avail. How do you select the lastest `point in time`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ?itemLabel ?population ?date {
   ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q50337; p:P1082 [pq:P585 ?date; ps:P1082 ?population]
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {?item p:P1082 [pq:P585 ?date_] FILTER (?date_ > ?date)}
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fdate%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ50337%3B%20p%3AP1082%20%5Bpq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%3B%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%5D%0A%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fitem%20p%3AP1082%20%5Bpq%3AP585%20%3Fdate_%5D%20FILTER%20%28%3Fdate_%20%3E%20%3Fdate%29%7D%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

If you really need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ?itemLabel ?date ?population {
  {
  SELECT ?item ?date ?pop {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q50337; p:P1082 [pq:P585 ?date; ps:P1082 ?pop]
  }
  } .
  {
  SELECT ?item (MAX(?date) AS ?date) {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q50337; p:P1082 [pq:P585 ?date]
  } GROUP BY ?item
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fdate%20%3Fpopulation%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fdate%20%3Fpop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ50337%3B%20p%3AP1082%20%5Bpq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%3B%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpop%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D.%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%28MAX%28%3Fdate%29%20AS%20%3Fdate%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ50337%3B%20p%3AP1082%20%5Bpq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%5D%0A%20%20%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

With Blazegraph's named subqueries:

```
SELECT ?item ?date ?population
WITH {
  SELECT * { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q50337; p:P1082 [pq:P585 ?date; ps:P1082 ?population] }} AS %all {
  {
  SELECT ?item (MAX(?date) AS ?date) { include %all } GROUP BY ?item
  }
  include %all
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fdate%20%3Fpopulation%0AWITH%20%7B%0A%20%20SELECT%20%2a%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ50337%3B%20p%3AP1082%20%5Bpq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%3B%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%5D%20%7D%20%7D%20AS%20%25all%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%28MAX%28%3Fdate%29%20AS%20%3Fdate%29%20%7B%20include%20%25all%20%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20include%20%25all%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)